# Keras RNN accuracy doesn't improve

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

I'm trying to improve my model so it can become a bit more accurate. Right now I'm training the model and get this as my training and validation accuracy.

For every epoch I get an training accuracy of 0.0003 and an validation accuracy of 0. I know this isn't good but I don't know how I can fix this.

Data is normalized with the minmax scaler. 4 of the 8 features are normalized (other 4 are hour, day, day_of_week and month)

**Update:**
I've also tried to normalize the entire dataset and it doesn't make a differance

```
scaling = MinMaxScaler(feature_range=(0,1)).fit(df[cols])
df[[cols]] = scaling.transform(df[[cols]])
```

My model: The shape is (5351, 1, 8)

and the input_shape is (1, 8)

```
model = keras.Sequential()
model.add(keras.layers.Bidirectional(keras.layers.LSTM(2,input_shape=(X_train.shape[1], X_train.shape[2]), return_sequences=True, activation='linear')))
model.add(keras.layers.Dense(1))
model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer='Adamax', metrics=['acc'])

history = model.fit(
    X_train, y_train,
    epochs=200,
    batch_size=24,
    validation_split=0.35,
    shuffle=False,
)
```

i tried using the answer of this question:
[Keras model accuracy not improving](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54231049/keras-model-accuracy-not-improving)
but it didn't work

Comment: Does it solve anything if return_sequence parameter from the LSTM should is set as False ?

Comment: nope, it doesn't solve it. the strange thing is I still get a 70% accurate prediction vs the test data if I manually compare the two

Comment: Is this a classification or regression model ? Because the loss and metric you set are incompatible.

Comment: regression model

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `mean_sqared_error` loss is for regression tasks while a `acc` metric is for classification problems. So it makes no sense to use them together.

If you work on a classification problem, use `binary_crossentropy` or `categorical_crossentropy` as loss and keep the metric parameter as you did.

If it is a regression tasks, change the metric to `[mse]` for mean squares error instead of `[acc]`.

Your model "works" and you have applied the standard formula for backpropagation by using the mean squares error loss. But measuring the accuracy will make Keras check if your model's output is EXACTLY equals to the expected values. Since the loss function is for regression, it will hardly ever be equal.

Three last points because that little change won't correct everything.

Firstly, your last dense layer should have an activation function. (It's safier)
Secondly, I'm pretty sure a Bidirectional+LSTM layer placed before a Dense layer should have a `return_sequences=False`. A LSTM layer (with or without Bidirectional) can return thé full séquence of vector (like a matrix) but a dense layer takes vectors as input. But in this case it will work because of the third point.
The last point is about the shape of your data. You have 5351 examples of shape (1, 8) each which a vector of size 8. But a LSTM layer takes a sequence of vectors still thé size of your séquence is one. I don't know if it is relevent to use an RNN type layer here.

Comment: thanks. works. it is a bit confusing if you're trying to build a model that needs to be accurate and there is an metric called accuracy. will mark answer as correct :)